# I came up with a way to format numbers to scientific notation, how can I call this function whenever I need it?

Tags: javascript, formatting, numbers

I just started learning js and so far am making good progress. I have encountered an issue tho, and the title should basically tell you everything you need to know, but here goes anyways.

For the project I want to realize eventually, I'll need rather big numbers. So I came up with the following to format them to scientific notation:

```
<script>

    var rawNumber = 172 ** 25;          // The number that shall be formatted into scientific notation
    var exponentDisplay = "e+";         // Self explainatory
    var numberRelevantDigits = 0;       // The digits displayed before the "e+"
    var numberExponent = 0;             // Self explainatory
    var formattedNumberDisplay = 0;     // What will be displayed
    
    
    function formatNumber() {                                                                   // The function triggered by clicking the button
        var numberExponent = Math.floor( Math.log(rawNumber) / Math.log(10) );                  // Calculating the exponent of the number in scientific notation
        var numberRelevantDigits = rawNumber / 10 ** numberExponent;                            // Dividing the number by 10 to the power of its exponent
        var numberRelevantDigits = numberRelevantDigits.toFixed(3);                             // Rounds the relevant digits to 3 decimals
        var formattedNumberDisplay = numberRelevantDigits + exponentDisplay + numberExponent;   // Adding the relevant digits, "e+" and the exponent into a string
        document.getElementById("formattedNumberDisplay").innerHTML = formattedNumberDisplay;   // Changing the display to the formatted number
        }
        
</script>
```

This works as intended, but I don't want to put this chunk of code whenever I need a number formatted. Is there a way (or rather: which is the way) to make it so I can just call that function whenever I need a number formatted? Even if I need use different variables?

Let me apologize again, since this has likely been answered a dozen times before, but I don't even have a clue what to even look for.

Thank y'all in advance.

Comment: Write your `formatNumber()` function so it takes parameters, e.g. `formatNumber(rawNumber, exponentDisplay, numberRelevantDigits, numberExponent, formattedNumberDisplay)` and returns the result. But you probably don't want to do the HTML element selection in that function. I.e., to make the function reusable, you might want it to do exactly one thing independent of UI elements.

Comment: I know this is for learning purposes, and therefore doing your own implementation is desired, but i just want to make sure that you know, that [Number.prototype.toExponential](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential) exists.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a js file and import it whenever you want
- also you should pass the variables to the functions instead of declaring them as a var
- inside funciton use const and let, you might some ugly bugs in the future if you don't.

Your file NumberFormater.js will look like:

```
 export formatNumber = (
       rawNumber,
       exponentDisplay,
       numberRelevantDigits,
       numberExponent,
       formattedNumberDisplay    
      ) => {
        let numberExponent = Math.floor( Math.log(rawNumber) / Math.log(10) );                  // Calculating the exponent of the number in scientific notation
        let numberRelevantDigits = rawNumber / 10 ** numberExponent;                            // Dividing the number by 10 to the power of its exponent
        let numberRelevantDigits = numberRelevantDigits.toFixed(3);                             // Rounds the relevant digits to 3 decimals
        let formattedNumberDisplay = numberRelevantDigits + exponentDisplay + numberExponent;   // Adding the relevant digits, "e+" and the exponent into a string
        document.getElementById("formattedNumberDisplay").innerHTML = formattedNumberDisplay;   // Changing the display to the formatted number

      }
```

then when needed:

```
 import { formatNumber } from './NumberFormater.js';
 const rawNumber = 172 ** 25;          // The number that shall be formatted into scientific notation
 const exponentDisplay = "e+";         // Self explainatory
 const numberRelevantDigits = 0;       // The digits displayed before the "e+"
 const numberExponent = 0;             // Self explainatory
 const formattedNumberDisplay = 0;     // What will be displayed

 formatNumber( rawNumber, exponentDisplay, numberRelevantDigits, numberExponent, formattedNumberDisplay);
```

read more on js modules https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules
Hope I've helped.